# options for building a realtime website

Tags: javascript, websocket, real-time

I'm going to build an webbased application which is controlling and monitoring tons of realtime data. think about few thousand valves pipes pumps and sensors.

Please list a technology stack you would use to build a realtime website with an educated guess about performance. The environment is 'ideal' all openstandards are available. so no IE6 etc backward compatibility is needed. Current and future proof technologies please.

server side:
database web-server - which one / combination makes it easy to support real-time pushing of data?

client side:
what kind of client environment (javascript Libraries) support showing and updating tons of realtime data?

Comment: You're being really vague about what you're trying to build, which is understandable because everyone thinks their idea will be stolen.  But to be honest, "I want to build a real-time web site" doesn't really tell us much about either your anticipated scale or needs, and just about any technology can be made to work if you configure it properly (case in point, many Web hosts tune Apache aggressively such that nginx/lighttpd/the next big fad is not necessary).

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to visualize a big machine. It has a couple of thousand actuators and sensors and They are slowly changeing value or state. It are many, so the browser probably needs to keep track of a few thousand objects and gets events and pushes events about at most few hunderd changes a minute.

Comment: You should also mention what kind of requirements you have in terms of availability and scale. For example, how many users do you expect? How many events? Is it ok for the entire system to be down if one user experiences an error? Is it necessary to run the system on multiple nodes, for scale or for availability? May you take the system down for code updates?

Comment: Hm it seems as if somebody doesn't like Socket.IO cause both answers got voted down. Would be interesting to know why. With the little information given, that is as good a starting point as any.

Comment: about 20 users at most. io is actual minimal pretty low. Availablity, Flexibility  are paramount.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at **[Goliath](http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/)**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look into [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) which works best with [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) and might be the best fit for handling many long lasting concurrent real time connections. I would say that the choice of the database depends more on where your real time data is coming from and how it is supposed to get in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to write a realtime app, but I've dabbled a bit with http://socket.io/ and node.js, and it's a joy to get started with.

App engine has a js channel api which seems nice. You should take a look to see if hosting on app engine is a option.

If you're dealing with "real time" stuff server-side, I recommend clojure for managing concurrent state.

Answer (score 0):

Me too. So I'm [writing a frame work](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/) that can do that. It's based on lighttpd front end, and multiple fcgi backend servers. The original Android was also tested with [another framework](http://code.google.com/p/powerdroid/) that is based on it. It's open source so you might want to use it as a starting point.